# Got css problem when implementing angular calendar

Tags: angular6, angular-calendar

I'm referred to [this thread](https://angular-calendar.com/#/kitchen-sink) : all is done.

But I got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRa4E.png) bellow the table. It seems that the tag `ng-template` is not working correctly.

The problem was a css issue. I got as warning:

> the stylesheet could not be loaded.
> https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/less/normalize.less

Also after clicking on the `start date` input text: I am getting this error:

> ERROR DOMException: CSSStyleSheet.cssRules getter: Not allowed to
> access cross-origin stylesheet

I can't figure it out. I don't now what I missed.
Could you please help me solving that issue?.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that you have to add the import `@import '../node_modules/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css';` to your **css file**.

HTH.

Comment: Big thanks @SariaEssid. you solve my issue. It workd as well now.