# Flatpickr NextJS+TS app - Uncaught DOMException: CSSStyleSheet.cssRules getter: Not allowed to access cross-origin stylesheet

Tags: css, next.js, flatpickr, domexception

I added Flatpickr to my project which has been working perfectly fine, however when checking in mobile view I get the following error when clicking on the input to open the calendar:

```
Uncaught DOMException: CSSStyleSheet.cssRules getter: Not allowed to access cross-origin stylesheet
```

I have trawled through SO and google to try and find a solution, but nothing seems to work. I have tried the solution proposed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63320540/got-css-problem-when-implementing-angular-calendar) but my project is using styled-components, which means I do not have a stylesheet to import. However I tried adding the import in my styled-component, I also tried adding a stylesheet which I imported in _app.tsx.

By playing with the responsive mode, I have noticed that the error activates when the screen width drops bellow 392px. Anything bigger than that and it all works perfectly fine.

Comment: Is this running on localhost? Have you checked CORS?

Comment: yes it is running localy and it does not appear to be an issue related to CORS.
I have opted for a temporary solution whereby on mobile I display the native inputs as opposed to the Flatpickr, as this seems to offer a better user experience.

Additionally the Flatpickr doc seems to indicate that this is what they do also, so I wonder if this issue is related to this fact?

Answer (score 1):

I have opted for a temporary solution whereby on mobile I display the native inputs as opposed to the Flatpickr, as this seems to offer a better user experience.
Additionally the Flatpickr doc seems to indicate that this is what they do also, so I am thinking that this error is due to that as I was hijacking the CSS in _app.js